# Google Maps API v3 - Map not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, maps

I used the Google Maps API v3 to create a map on http://voltmer-elektronik.de/kontakt.php, but the image tiles of the actual map aren't loading. Chrome's Developer Console doesn't give any errors.

EDIT: unfortunately the map got removed

Comment: Since you solved your problem, you should add an answer to it and accept that.

Comment: Works for me in Firefox.

Comment: RE Your edit: This is exactly why you're not allowed to link to live sites in your questions. Such questions are supposed to be closed as off-topic. Next time, please include the code in your question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

My script resizes the map, so I must trigger the map's resize event everytime I change it's size like this:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```